# Query Table not in Data Model Edmx

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Normally if we want to execute a sql statment via entity frame work we would do the following.

```
DbSqlQuery<Customer> data = db.Customers.SqlQuery(
    "select * from customers where country=@p0", "USA");
foreach(var cust in data)
{
 //do something with cust
}
```

But thats ok for tables that are within the data model my question is how do i do a raw query against a table that is not already in the data model. The reason being is that the software has what is called historic tables that is created the month and the year at the end of table so I cannot create these tables at runtime or would that be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the underlying connection and query these historical tables.

```
var history = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>( "SELECT Name FROM dbo.historical_table").ToList();
```

Take a look at the [following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592907.aspx)

**EDIT --** If you wish to retuned multiple fields you have to capture the results into a class with matching property names, and (at least) a parameterless constructor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new ConsoleApplication10.DBContext())
            {
                var list= db.Database.SqlQuery<DbResult>("SELECT display_name, country_code FROM dbo.mytable").ToList();
            }

        }
    }

    class DbResult
    {
        public string display_name { get; set; }
        public string country_code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what object does history then become ie how can i loop through the resutls or send to a class

Comment: also I am using entites as my selector so I am doing like above db.tablename
i am not using dbcontext in the method you showed

Comment: @david you can just use db.database rather than db.tablename. You have to capture the results into a class with matching property names, and (at least) a parameterless constructor: If you require i can update my answer with an example of this?

Comment: Yes please that would be most greatfull